# Can not install nodejs

Tags: node.js

my computer can not install Nodejs. 
Pic below

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that there should be any instance of node install on your computer, try to uninstall instance (if there is any ) then install again. You can try to install the stable version first

Comment: Google it, plenty of answers online
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/get-error-1723-there-is-a-problem-with-windows/3d68fc4b-c968-4796-a270-27027a52de3f?auth=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you [googled for the error you're getting](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+a+dll+required+for+this+install)?

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3431 says you should try either clearing your temp directory, running the installer as an admin, or disabling antivirus
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5759 says you might need to modify the privileges on your temp folder (if running as administrator doesn't help)
- More solutions here: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/333